# Fill Field textarea different select

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create selects and by choosing, fill the field in the "textarea". An example of what I did and what I'm trying to do. The image is edited. I don't know how to create more than one select that feeds the same textarea.

```js
function fillFild() {
  var myList = document.getElementById("myList");
  document.getElementById("fild").value = myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].value;
}

function fillFild1() {
  var myList = document.getElementById("myList1");
  document.getElementById("fild1").value = myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

```html
<form name="Form">
  Select your Device:
  <select id="myList" name="select_field" onchange="fillFild();">
    <option value="Laptop: ">Laptop</option>
    <option value="PC:">PC</option>
    <option value="Smartphone: ">Smartphone</option>
    <option value="Tablet: ">Tablet</option>
  </select>
  <form name="Form1">
    Select your Problem:
    <select id="myList1" name="select_field" onchange="fillFild1();">
      <option value="Software: ">Software</option>
      <option value="Hardware:">Hardware</option>
    </select>

    <textarea name="TextArea" id="fild1" style="position:absolute;left:23px;top:153px;width:394px;height:119px;z-index:5;" rows="7" cols="47" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
  </form>
```

[Illustrating what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtViB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you have the solution to your question:

```js
const selectElements = document.querySelectorAll('.select_field');
const textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');

[].slice.call(selectElements).map(el => el.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const selcted = e.target.value;
  if (selcted !== '') {
    textArea.value += selcted + '\n';
  }
}));
```

```html
<div>
  Select your Device:
  <select id="myList" name="select_field" class="select_field">
    <option value="">-- choose --</option>
    <option value="Laptop:">Laptop</option>
    <option value="PC:">PC</option>
    <option value="Smartphone:">Smartphone</option>
    <option value="Tablet:">Tablet</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  Select your Problem:
  <select id="myList1" name="select_field" class="select_field">
    <option value="">-- choose --</option>
    <option value="Software:">Software</option>
    <option value="Hardware:">Hardware</option>
  </select>
</div>
<textarea name="TextArea" id="fild1" rows="7" cols="47" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. I am still learning javascript and I was confused how to incorporate this code into my old one. I just tried to change what I already had and it "broke" not having the same result seen when running here.